# How to license part of the file?

Tags: open-source, licensing, gnu

I have modified some files of an open source project under GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE to add some specific features.
I would add the same license for the part of the code written by me.
How i should do this?
What is the preamble that have to be added to files modified?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually because of the Gnu GPL definition, if the code is under GPL license and if any changes made to the code then the total code should be licensed under the GPL compatible  license. But usually everyone license the code under the same GPL license.

[GPL frequently used questions](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#ModifyGPL)

Comment: The two licenses are compatible, are both GPL. So if i understood, i have to add my preamble under the pre existing preamble? Or substitute the pre existing preamble with mine?

Comment: from the given link :"Can I modify the GPL and make a modified license?    It is possible to make modified versions of the GPL, but it tends to have practical consequences.

    You can legally use the GPL terms (possibly modified) in another license provided that you call your license by another name and do not include the GPL preamble, and provided you modify the instructions-for-use at the end enough to make it clearly different in wording and not mention GNU . If you want to use our preamble in a modified license, please write to <licensing@gnu.org> for permission."